# PHP open source multi user login

Tags: php, authentication

I've had, I believe, a great business idea so I’ve decided to try develop a minimum viable product myself.

A long, long time ago I taught myself asp classic and built a couple of apps so I have some development experience.  I haven't done much since (apart from a few basic php sites for friends) and I'm not a natural coder though and find it quite hard going.

Bearing this in mind and considering the importance of proper security I'm trying to give myself a head start so have been looking for an open source (or paid if it’s not too much) PHP single-db multi-tenant framework or site template.

The idea I am working on is aimed towards very small businesses and in a nutshell:

User A should be able to login and add and retrieve data that only he/she can see.
User B should be able to login and add and retrieve data that only he/she can see.

It’s pretty standard stuff but as far as I can tell, everything I’ve found so far is aimed towards managing multiple users across a single secure area (e.g. User Frosting) rather than multiple users across their own secure areas

Does such a template/framework exist?

Alternatively, can somebody recommend a PHP framework that’s good for beginners with a decent supply of starter templates/tutorials? Innomatic keeps cropping up in my searches but I fear that it may be more advanced and more “full-featured” than necessary.

Any advice, opinions or pointers towards relevant material would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/) is the framework that is trending as the most popular, easy to learn, and widely extensible with open source contributors. [Also, Here is a great link that discusses learning it while building a user/group/roles based project.](https://gist.github.com/anchetaWern/4223764)  That should be exactly what you need on all fronts.

Comment: Yes Laravel would do nicely. Also you could take a look at Yii2. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

Comment: Many thanks for the input. I've had a bit of a search around based on your reccomendations and found Landlord  for Laravel/Lumen. 
ooks like it could be perfect